# How do I clear input field in Intern JS?

Tags: selenium, intern, leadfoot

I have written a small piece of code for inline editing table fields. When the user clicks, the element is removed and on its place an `input` field is created. After modification is done the `input` field is removed and a `span` element with the new value is created. Let me show some background code.

**html code before click:**

```
<div>
 <table id='mytable'>
 <thead>
...
 </thead>
 <tbody id='mybody'>
 ...
 <tr class="tr-edit even" role="row">
  <td>escape substitution</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td id="268435506">
   <span class="td-span-edit">hola</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 ...
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**html code after click:**

```
<div>
 <table id='mytable'>
 <thead>
...
 </thead>
 <tbody id='mybody'>
 ...
 <tr class="tr-edit even" role="row">
  <td>escape substitution</td>
  <td>TEXT</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td id="268435506">
   <input class="td-input-edit" type="text" value='hola'/>
  </td>
 </tr>
 ...
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

The modified value is sent to a server when the input is out of focus, `blur`, or when `ENTER_KEY` is pressed.

On the other hand I have written a functional test in intern js to simulate such inline editing. My functional test looks like this:

```
tdd.test('inline editing',function(){
return this.remote
 .findById('268435506')
     .then(function(param){
        return this.parent
            .moveMouseTo(param)
            ;
    })
    .click()
    .clearValue()
    .type('666')
    .executeAsync(function(done){
        promise
            .then(function(){
                done();
            });
    })
    .getVisibleText()
    .then(function(text){
        assert.strictEqual(text,
            '666',
            'typed value should be stored');
    })
 .end()
;
)};
```

The issue is that the test fails with exceptions on both chrome and firefox.

1. chrome: `InvalidElementState: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it`
2. firefox: `UnknownError: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.`

I have [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B1o7.png) when the exception occurs and the input field is clearly focused. So you should be able to edit it. I tried to remove the `.clearValue()` call from the chain but then, as expected, the assert fails.

**Question:** How do I test this inline editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see is because you try to `clearValue()` on the wrong element, e.g. the `td` element with id `268435506`. When the user clicks on the `td` element the click handler removes the original `span` element and places an `input` element so that the user can type a new value. When this happens you should use `find*` to 'select' the appropriate element and perform the correspondent operation. Let me illustrate this using your initial code:

```
tdd.test('inline editing',function(){
 return this.remote
 .findById('268435506')
    .then(function(param){
        return this.parent
            .moveMouseTo(param)
            ;
    })
    .click()
    .findByClassName('td-input-edit')
        .clearValue()
        .type('666\uE007')//enter button to end or click outside
        .executeAsync(function(done){
            promise
                .then(function(){
                    done();
                });
        })
    .end()
    .findByClassName('td-span-edit')
        .getVisibleText()
        .then(function(text){
            assert.strictEqual(text,
                '666',
                'typed value should be stored');
        })
    .end()
 .end()
    ;
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set text field attribute "value" to blank instead of using clearValue() and then type the new value

```
.setAttribute("value", "")
```

Comment: There is no such an function call in leadfoot. At least I don't see it. Anyways I found the problem for which I will provide an answer shortly.